# keep selected tab on page refresh using angular 2 dynamic routing

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular2-routing

I am trying to refresh selected tab(suppose tab2 ) but only i am getting UI load for the same tab and its highlights to tab1. I am not getting to refresh same tab in angular 2 using dynamic routing and bootstrap.

Here is my code for your reference

```
<a routerLink="/tab1" class="placeholder col-xs-2 item"  (click)="onMenuClick('tab1')" *ngIf="authorizationService.isTab1View">
            <span class="placeholderimg"><i id="tabCust" class="fa fa-users fa-menu-top" [style.color]="tab1Selected"></i></span>
            <p class="placeholdertext">{{ 'MENU.tab1' | translate }}</p>
        </a>

        <a routerLink="/tab2" class="placeholder col-xs-2 item" (click)="onMenuClick('tab2')" *ngIf="authorizationService.isTab2View">
            <span class="placeholderimg"><i id="tabSite" class="fa fa-building-o fa-menu-top" [style.color]="tab2Selected"></i></span>
            <p class="placeholdertext">{{ 'MENU.tab2' | translate }}</p>
        </a>
```

I am new in angular 2. Can anyone help me to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use `routerLinkActive` directive in your `anchor` tag like this -

```
<a routerLink="/tab1" routerLinkActive="active-link" class="placeholder col-xs-2 item"  (click)="onMenuClick('tab1')" *ngIf="authorizationService.isTab1View">
    <span class="placeholderimg"><i id="tabCust" class="fa fa-users fa-menu-top" [style.color]="tab1Selected"></i></span>
    <p class="placeholdertext">{{ 'MENU.tab1' | translate }}</p>
</a>

<a routerLink="/tab2" routerLinkActive="active-link" class="placeholder col-xs-2 item" (click)="onMenuClick('tab2')" *ngIf="authorizationService.isTab2View">
    <span class="placeholderimg"><i id="tabSite" class="fa fa-building-o fa-menu-top" [style.color]="tab2Selected"></i></span>
    <p class="placeholdertext">{{ 'MENU.tab2' | translate }}</p>
</a>
```

Where `active-link` is a css class that you can use to customize your active anchor tag.

Comment: thanks for your reply but after adding routerLinkActive in my solution .still problem occur ...